# NiFi: content_repository is full despite settings in the nifi.properties

Tags: apache-nifi, hortonworks-dataflow

I am seeing that the disk partition where the content_repository is located is 85% full. When I look in the repository folder I see file fragments that are older than 2 week.

My first question is what will happen if the partition is 100% full. And the second question is how do I keep the partition from becoming 100% full?

My settings in the nifi.properties are as follows:

```
nifi.content.repository.implementation=org.apache.nifi.controller.repository.FileSystemRepository
nifi.content.repository.directory.default=/var/mydir/content_repository
nifi.content.repository.archive.max.retention.period=12 hours
nifi.content.repository.archive.max.usage.percentage=50%
nifi.content.repository.archive.enabled=true
nifi.content.repository.always.sync=false
```

I am on NiFi 1.9.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a bug in Apache NiFi 1.9.1 which causes this. It was fixed in a recent release 1.9.2 ([Release Notes](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/NIFI/Release+Notes#ReleaseNotes-Version1.9.2)). The upgrade will fix the issue ([NIFI-6150](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-6150)).

Comment: Thanks Andy. I will upgrade.